# How to run .sh file on Windows 7 through Cygwin?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, sh

I have to use a package on my **Windows 7** OS but the package comes only with the `.sh` file so I have to use bash and hence Cygwin to run on my machine.

But I am kinda familiar with Windows but completely new to Cygwin and shell programming.

Suppose I have a `run.sh` file in `/cygdrive/c/Users/myUserName/Desktop/software/myPackage/bin`, how should I run it in Cygwin?

Downloaded Cygwin and in the terminal I navigate to that directory and type `run.sh` enter but it complains

```
$ run.sh
-bash: run.sh: command not found
```

I am asking this because I generally understand in Windows you can just navigate to the directory and run the `.bat` file and that's it?

How does this work for Cygwin? Any suggestion are highly appreciated!

Comment: By default, the current directory is not in the PATH. Take anubhava's advice.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can run it as:

```
bash run.sh
```

Or else:

```
chmod +x run.sh
./run.sh
```

Comment: I haven't played with cygwin in years.  Is `unix2dos` required to translate line terminators?

Comment: Not really needed in this case.